# there's a problem when I build my own crosstool with crosstool-4.3

Tags: gcc, embedded-linux

When compiling cross-compiler tool crosstool-0.43 (for arm9) on the CentOS 7.5 64-bit system, I encountered the following error：

**cc    -c -o flat_bl.o /home/muhuo/arm-linux-project/transplant-test/build-tools/crosstool-0.43/build/arm-9tdmi-linux/gcc-4.1.0-glibc-2.3.2/binutils-2.16.1/gprof/flat_bl.m
/home/muhuo/arm-linux-project/transplant-test/build-tools/crosstool-0.43/build/arm-9tdmi-linux/gcc-4.1.0-glibc-2.3.2/binutils-2.16.1/gprof/flat_bl.m:2:2: error: expected identifier or ??before ??token**

**%         the percentage of the total running time of the**

**^**

I don't know what the *. m file in binutils-2.16.1 is. Whether I need to install some other tools before?
From the picture above, Compiling *.m file with GCC should be wrong.
I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: please, do NOT post pictures. Put the console output as text. Search engines are not designed (yet) to parse your console text pictures and reference them correctly for other users that might face the same issue. SO has not (yet ?) provided a tool to do the conversion from image to text for you, and it is probably not a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is a builtin '.m.o' suffix rule which triggers with a higher priority than the '.c.o' suffix rule.  There was an attempt to disable this rule under [PR2587](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2587) but because it is an old-style suffix rule this doesn't work.

There are two possible solutions, one is to remove all builtin rules by adding the line `.MAKEFLAGS: -r` to `binutils/gprof/Makefile.in` somewhere, or else more correctly change the `.SUFFIXES:` line in the same file so that the '.m' comes after '.c', thus changing the rule priority.